# Must boundary operator have fixed point?

Tags: general-topology

Let $(S,\tau)$ be a topology. Let $X \subseteq S$.

Define a sequence of sets as follows:

$$a_0=X, a_{n+1} = \partial a_n$$

where $\partial$ denotes the boundary operator.

Must there exist $k \in \Bbb N$ such that $a_{k} = a_{k+1}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, in fact $k \in \{0,1,2\}$. The 2 occurs for, for example, $\mathbb Q \subseteq \mathbb R$. Then $\partial \mathbb Q = \mathbb R$, while $\partial \mathbb R = \emptyset$, and $\partial \emptyset = \emptyset$.

To see that $k \leq 2$, note first that $\partial X = \overline{X} \setminus X^\circ$. In particular, $\partial X$ is always closed. This means that $\overline{\partial X} = \partial X$, so that $\partial \partial X = \partial X \setminus (\partial X)^\circ$. Hence, $\partial \partial X$ is just $\partial X$ with any non-trivial open subset removed. This means that $(\partial \partial X)^\circ = \emptyset$, and of course $\partial \partial X$ is again closed. Thus in particular, $$\partial\partial\partial X = \overline{\partial\partial X}\setminus (\partial\partial X)^\circ = \partial\partial X \setminus \emptyset = \partial \partial X.$$

Comment: Isn't $]0,1[$ a non-trivial open subset of $\partial \Bbb Q$?

Comment: For $X=\Bbb Q$, $\partial \partial X = \partial \Bbb R = \varnothing \ne \partial X$

Comment: Oops, silly error. Fixed now.